# A codable structure contains a protocol property

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a protocol which is inherited from codable

```
protocol OrderItem:Codable {
    var amount:Int{get set}
    var isPaid:Bool{get set}
}
```

And a struct conform this protocol

```
struct ProductItem:OrderItem {
    var amount = 0
    var isPaid = false
    var price = 0.0
}
```

However when I put this structure into a codable structure, I got errors

```
struct Order:Codable {
    var id:String
    var sn:String = ""
    var items:[OrderItem] = []
    var createdAt:Int64 = 0
    var updatedAt:Int64 = 0
}
```

The errors are

```
Type 'Order' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
Type 'Order' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
```

But if I change items:[OrderItem] to items:[ProductItem] , everything works!

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot do that because a protocol only states what you **must** do. So when you conform your protocol `X` to `Codable`, it only means that any type that conforms to `X` must also conform to `Codable` but it won't provide the required implementation. You probably got confused because `Codable` does not require you to implement anything when all your types already are `Codable`. If `Codable` asked you to, say, implement a function called `myFunction`, your `OrderItem` would then lack the implementation of that function and the compiler would make you add it.

Here is what you can do instead:

```
struct Order<T: OrderItem>: Codable {
   var id:String
   var sn:String = ""
   var items: [T] = []
   var createdAt:Int64 = 0
   var updatedAt:Int64 = 0
}
```

You now say that `items` is a generic type that conforms to `OrderItem`.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

It's worth mentioning that if you have a property of an array and the type is a protocol: `let arrayProtocol: [MyProtocol]` and the array contains multiple types that all conform to `MyProtocol`, you will have to implement your own `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` to get the values and `func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws` to encode them.

So for example:

```
protocol MyProtocol {}
struct FirstType: MyProtocol {}
struct SecondType: MyProtocol {}

struct CustomObject: Codable {
   let arrayProtocol: [MyProtocol]

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case firstTypeKey
      case secondTypeKey
   }
}
```

so our decode will look like this:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
   let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
   // FirstType conforms to MyProtocol
   let firstTypeArray = try values.decode([FirstType].self, forKey: .firstTypeKey)
   // SecondType conforms to MyProtocol
   let secondTypeArray = try values.decode([SecondType].self, forKey: .secondTypeKey)
   // Our array is finally decoded
   self.arrayProtocol: [MyProtocol] = firstTypeArray + secondTypeArray
}
```

and the same for encoded, we need to cast to the actual type before encoding:

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
   var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
   let firstActualTypeArray = arrayProtocol.compactMap{$0 as? FirstType}
   let secondActualTypeArray = arrayProtocol.compactMap{$0 as? SecondType}

   try container.encode(firstActualTypeArray, forKey: .firstTypeKey)
   try container.encode(secondActualTypeArray, forKey: .secondTypeKey)
}
```

Comment: I might be confused on the way try works, if any of the try statements throw an error, wouldn't the initializer immediately throw an error? I'm going to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Codable is a type alias for Encodable and Decodable.

Therefore if you're implementing it you need to implement the following two functions.

1. `func encode(to: Encoder)`
2. `init(from: Decoder)`

Comment: It is because `OrderItem` is a protocol. S/he will not need to implement those since her/his types already contain `Codable` types.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Pink