# How/where to resolve a generic property type

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I ran into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45400470/2019384).

When I adapted my code to that solution, I ran into another issue: I don't know, how/where to resolve the generic type.

I ended up, modifying all the classes/structs up to my ViewController to be generic (and I think, I would have go even beyond, to make it compile). Which cannot be the way to go, I guess? This has to stop somewhere? I mean, this is just a detail of one Property.

So e.g.:

```
protocol PhotoData { ... }

// different data for each Provider
class DropboxData: PhotoData { ... } 
class PhotoLibraryData: PhotoData { ... }

struct Image<T: PhotoData> {
    let image: UIImage
    let photoData: T
}

struct ImageConfiguration<T: PhotoData> { // I want to make this Codable to be able store it on disk
    let image: Image<T>
    ...
}

class ViewController<T: PhotoData>: UIViewController {
    let config: ImageConfiguration<T>
    ...
}
```

I'm completely stumped on this right now. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: There is nothing in your example that sets constraints on when it's useful to have a concrete type or when it's a problem to have one. I have no idea how to help.

Comment: The Problem is, that `Codable` doesn't work using the Protocol without having a concrete type (see problem from the link, I posted). I also updated the example.

Comment: This example still doesn't show why `ViewController` should be generic or not generic. There is nothing inherently wrong with this code.

Comment: It seems that you want to create a shortcut for the shortcut. Consider that `Codable` supports only a very restricted type set (the supported types of JSON and property list). It's rather impossible to make that generic.

Comment: If you don't like the default Codable implementation, have you considered writing your own? That would help you understand the kind of restrictions that the compiler puts on its default implementations, and it would probably solve your problem without having to make the world generic.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your support guys.. maybe I'll stick with the old NSCoding stuff for now.